# Помогите понять, как сделать интерфейс в iOS

Tags: ios

Вот есть приложение Фото в айфонах, и когда заходишь в фото - внизу скролл из фото
как сделать такой же?
есть ли у iOS родное решение?

Comment: Есои вы про полосу с горизонтальной прокруткой миниатюр фото, то используйте UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

Элемантарно используейте UICollectionView для создания такого интерфейса

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]